# Waiting time for a better offer

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

This exercise is form "A Second Course in Stochastic Processes, Band 2" - Karlin.

> Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a family of i.i.d. random variables. Define $N:=\inf \{n\in\mathbb{N}: X_n>X_1\}$.
>
> Determine $P[N=k]$ and $E[N]$.

Although this exercise is from a stochastic processes book, I have no experience in this field. However, I still wanted to try.

**My attempt:**
As the random variables are independent, I get

$$P[N=k]=P[X_2\le X_1]P[X_3\le X_1]...P[X_{k-1}\le X_1]P[X_k>X_1]\\ =\prod_{i=2}^{k-1}P[X_i\le X_1]\cdot P[X_k > X_1].$$

Now I use that the family is identically distributed and get

$P[N=k]=P[X_2\le X_1]^{k-2}\cdot P[X_k>X_1].$

Unfortunately, here I am stuck and don't know if the approach is correct.

Comment: Yeah you are going in the correct direction. Also you should note that $X_1$ is also a random variable so you will have to account its probability too. Currently you have evaluated $\Pr[N = k|X_1]$.

Comment: There's something wrong with the problem you've stated.  Suppose $X_i$ are 50:50 bernoulis.  Then $\sum_{k} P[N=k] =\frac{1}{2}$ and $N$ is a defective random variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ P(N>k) = P(\bigcap_{i=2}^{k} X_i \leq X_1) = \mathbb E [P(\bigcap_{i=2}^k X_i\le X_1|X_1)] = \mathbb E [\prod_{i=2}^kP(X_i\le X_1|X_1)] = \mathbb E [F(X_1)^{k-1}] $$
where $F$ denotes the CDF of $X_1$.
Hence
$$ \mathbb E N = \sum_{k\geq 0} P(N>k) = 1+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(N>k) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb EF[(X_1)^{k-1} ]  $$
Now since $F(X_1) \sim U[0,1]$ we have
$$ \mathbb E[F(X_1)^k] = \int_0^1 x^k dx = \frac{1}{k+1}  $$
and so \begin{align*} P(N=1)&=0 \\ P(N=k) &= P(N>k)-P(N>k-1) = \frac{1}{k}-\frac1{k-1}\\ \mathbb E N &= \infty \end{align*}
EDIT: the previous case is when $F$ is continuous! 
If it is not, then: if the support of $X_1$ is finite, there is positive probability that $X_1$ assumes the maximum value, thus on this event $N=\infty$, hence $EN =\infty$. It is a bit tricky to compute the probabilities, since $F$ has jumps and it does not have a proper inverse. Note that
$$P (F(X_1)<x ) =\sum_{k:F(k)< x} P(X_1=k).$$
The usual way to define a pseudoinverse is
$$ F^{-1} (q)= \sup\{ x: F(x)< q \} $$
or
$$ \inf\{x: q< F(x)\}. $$

Comment: Very elegant! How do you know that $F(X_1)\sim U([0,1])$?

Comment: Well it is clear that $F(X_1)$ assumes values from $[0,1]$ only, furthermore $P(F(X_1)<X) = P(X_1< F^{-1} (x)) = F(F^{-1}(x))=x.$

Comment: Interesting, so this means that really for *every* random variable $Y$ its distribution function $F(Y)$ is uniformly distributed?

Comment: Not every, but for those that have a proper inverse, yes. E.g. if F is strictly increasing and continuous. In other cases one has to be careful.